# C program crashes when calling fopen

Tags: c, crash

I'm new here and have a problem I cannot solve by searching in the Internet.

My program just crashes when I call fopen once more.
Just a small description:
The program reads files line after line. There are 2 possible formats for those lines, thats why I have to differentiate between them. When a File is in the Format, that corresponds to the "else"-branch. The Program works fine without crashing. 
The other format however, that results in the "if"-branch leads to a crash.
I hope the part of the sourcecode is enough for you guys.

```
    FILE *f = fopen("DATA.txt", "a+");
    for (int m = 0; m<listsize; m += 1) {
    .
    .
    .
    FILE *CSV = fopen(name, "r");
    FILE *pufferfile = fopen("puf.txt", "w+");        
    .
    .
    .
    char puffer[90];
    while (fgets(puffer, 90, CSV))
    {
        fputs(puffer, pufferfile);
        fseek(pufferfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
        if ((strstr(puffer, "\"")) != NULL) {
            fscanf(pufferfile, "%d,%d/%d/%d,%d:%d:%d,\"  %[^'\"]%s%*[ \"]%s  %[^'\"]%s  %[^'\"]%s\n", &row, &month, &day, &year, &hours, &minutes, &seconds, w_h, we, wj, w_t);
            fseek(pufferfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
            h_0 = atoi(w_h);
            h_0 += ((float)atoi(w_h + (strlen(w_h)) - 1) / (float)10);
            hum = h_0;
            t_0 = atoi(w_t);
            t_0 += ((float)atoi(w_t + (strlen(w_t)) - 1) / (float)10);
            temp = t_0;
        }
        else {
            fscanf(pufferfile, "%d,%d/%d/%d,%d:%d:%d,%f,%s\n", &row, &month, &day, &year, &hours, &minutes, &seconds, &hum, we);
            fseek(pufferfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
            t_1 = (int)we[4] - 48;
            t_2 = (int)we[5] - 48;
            t_0 = (int)we[7] - 48;
            if (we[6] == ',') {
                t_3 = 0;
            }
            else {
                t_3 = t_0;
            }
            temp = t_1 * 10 + t_2 + t_3 / 10;
        }
        fprintf(f, "      %02d.%02d.%d\t ;\t %02d:%02d:%02d\t ;\t    %.1f\t ;\t %.1f\n", day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds, temp, hum);

    }
    fclose(CSV);
    fclose(pufferfile);
    remove(name);


}
remove("puf.txt");
fclose(f);

int index = 0;
FILE *woo = fopen("DATA_daily.txt", "w+"); //HERE it crashes
```

Edit: Sorry I added a few lines more to the code so you can understand it better. It doesn't crash directly in the "if"-branch. The point is that if the program reads a file that is formatted a specific way it chooses the if-branch. And somehow then it crashes when calling the last "fopen("DATA_daily.txt", "w+");".
The same data formatted the way that the program chooses the "else"-branch doesn't result in a crash.
Let me explain it shortly. I have a List (of size lenghtsize) of filenames.
The program opens it, reads the lines and decides, how the line is formatted.
According to that it reads the values and puts it in another file (here "DATA.txt").
After the program crashes I can see the file DATA.txt and it looks fine. Every single line got written in there.

The possible 2 line formats look like that:

```
1,4/4/2017,13:03:42,"  000028,9",       %RH,"  000023,1",  DEGREE C ---> resulting in the if-branch, causes crash
and
1,4/4/2017,13:03:42,28.9,       %RH,23.1,  DEGREE C  ---> resulting in the else branch, NO crash
```

Comment: You don't solve programming bugs with the internet. You solve them wirh a debugger..

Comment: I don't see any `fopen` calls in the `if` branch, or any calls to any functions that might call `fopen`, so how can it be crashing on `fopen` in that branch?

Comment: Is it possible that `fclose(f);` is actually crashing?  What's `f`?  You also use it previously in your call to `fprintf`, but it doesn't seem to be initialized anywhere.

Comment: You are not checking the return value from `fopen` before using it. You are removing the file specified by `name` after you close it on first use, are you ever reinitializing before trying to open it again? Always post an [MCVE], it doesn't have to be your entire program, just enough that we can compile and verify what's going on. By the time you produce an MCVE, you usually find the problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I notice your code in the "if" branch does not check the return values from fscanf, which is the first thing to fix.  For example:

```
rc = fscanf(...);
if ( rc != 11 )
{
  // handle error
}
```

Next I would check the way you have defined w_h and w_t, and change the %s.  I just checked the MSDN page for scanf() and it warns you must always specify a width for the %s format (eg. use %32s instead), to avoid buffer overruns.

I would also ensure that w_h and w_t are null-terminated before passing them as an argument to strlen or atoi.  For example:

```
char w_t[MAXLEN];
rc = fscanf(...);
if ( rc != 11 ) { /* handle error */ }
w_t[sizeof(w_t)-1] = '\0';
a = atoi(w_t);
```

But now I notice in fact you wrote

```
atoi(w_t + (strlen(w_t))
```

which won't do anything useful because, even when w_t is successfully null-terminated, this will pass into atoi a pointer to the trailing null byte.  I don't know what atoi will make of this, but it will probably return 0.  Always.

Anyway these are the first things I would fix.  As someone else has said, you will get somewhere faster if you use a debugger.  Or printfs.